# excel vba - copy file from one folder to another but if file exists do not overwrite?

Tags: excel, vba, copy

Can someone please show me a way of copying a file from one folder to another using vba but with a condition to say if file already exists do not overwrite?

here is my code:

```
If Target.Column = Range("BL1").Column And Target.Row > 14 Then
  FileCopy "\\UKSH000-FILE06\purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\assets\audit.xls", "\\UKSH000-FILE06\purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\ATTACHMENTS\" & Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row) & "\audit.xls"
 End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplifying your paths a bit for clarity:

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fs.FileExists("\\path\to\destination" & stuff & "\audit.xls") Then
    FileCopy "\\path\to\source\audit.xls", "\\path\to\destination\" & stuff & "\audit.xls"
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Really old thread but apparently the VBA FileCopy statement does not support the boolean parameter described in Kunal's answer (https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filecopy-statement). On the other hand, the CopyFile method of the Scripting.FileSystemObject does (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/copyfile-method).

```
FileSystemObject.CopyFile "c:\mydocuments\letters\file.doc", "c:\tempfolder\", True
```

Answer (score 1):

FileCopy (sourceString, DestinationString, Boolean)
Set Boolean to TRUE if destination can be overwritten, by default it is false.

Comment: FileSystemObject has a Boolean to overwrite, but FileCopy does not.